# How can I easily install indicators for lxpanel?

Tags: 10.04, lxde, lxpanel

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.3 Server Edition and I need to get the indicator applets for LXpanel. I've tried looking through http://packages.ubuntu.com, but the package for lxpanel indicators is only for Maverick and above, and I don't want to get caught in dependency hell. Is there any way I can easily install indicators for lxpanel in Lucid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [PPA for LXDE](https://launchpad.net/~lxde/+archive/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=lucid) on Lucid created by the same developers as Lubuntu.  As for all PPAs - use with care and have a good backup before usage.

Examining the `lxpanel` package in this PPA - the `lxpanel-indicator-plugin` is available.

You can add the PPA by adding it to `/etc/apt/sources.list` - you will need to install the GPG key separately.

Alternatively (and more easy to do), install the package `python-software-properties` and then use `add-apt-repository` i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lxde/ppa
sudo apt-get upgrade
```